# Is there an equivalent idiom for "when you get right down to it" in Portuguese?

Tags: expressões-idiomáticas, expressões-equivalentes

"when you get right down to it" is an idiom meaning "all things considered"

e.g. "[**When you get right down to it**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=when+you+get+right+down+to+it&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=9OrHVY-0Equk8we7z4HYDQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=when+you+get+right+down+to+it&safe=off&tbm=bks), a human being is not a physical entity. A human being is a piece of software. Body cells are constantly dying and being replaced."

Is there a set phrase or idiom which conveys the same in Portuguese?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which option to choose depends a bit on the context, but you could say:

- *No fundo* [or the more emphatic *no fundo, no fundo*]
- *No final das contas* [or *no fim das contas*]
- *Na hora do "vamos ver"* [or *"do vamo vê"*]
- *No frigir dos ovos*
- *Ao fim e ao cabo*

The last two are rarely used in informal situations, at least in Brazil. They also seem to be less known to younger generations.